# How to check if item exist within multiple arrays

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Users have the option to add their photo to a category if they select it.

The categories are displayed in the form of a horizontal collection view. If a photo is added into a category, the collection view will show a checkmark, indicating that the photo is added to a specific category.

Users have the option to edit their photo if they want to add or remove their photo from a category. The problem I am having is checking if the users postId exist within a category.

If postId exist within a category, show a checkmark on that collection view item

If a postId does not exist within a category, that collection view item should not have a checkmark.

Here is the piece of code I am struggling with, how can I check each category in the database reference, and see if the postId exist in any of them.

And if the postId does exist, how can I indicate to the user that specific collection view item contains the postId?

In the code example below, I'm not sure how to check all categories, so instead I just choose `queryOrderedBy(byChild: "socks)` because I know I have a postId in the category.

```swift
 var trendsCell: TrendsCollectionCell!

 guard let post = self.postToEdit else { return }

FEMALE_TRENDS_REF.queryOrdered(byChild: "socks").queryEqual(toValue: post.postId).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    self.trendsCell.trendCheckmark.isHidden = false
                    print("Show checkmarks on cell items that contain postId")
                } else {
                    self.trendsCell.trendCheckmark.isHidden = true
                    print("Hide checkmark on cell items that do not contain postId")

                }
            })
```

The result I get is - The checkmark is hidden on a collection view item when it should not be, if any categories contain a postId, that specific collection view cell should display the checkmark

Here is the json

```
 "female-trend-posts" : {
    "socks" : {

      "-M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8" : 1
    },
    "hats" : {
      "-M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8" : 1,
      "-M11r5zcKvZYHDKhVzKF" : 1,

    "shoes" : {
      "-M0uaeDL7dD1eFf1tC0k" : 1,
      "-M11zGpEBwKtDRp99NOD" : 1
    },
```

The postId is **M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8** How can I check if the post Id exist in socks, hats and, shoes? Not just socks?

Answer (score 0):

We can use recursion to check an entire json.

We first turn it into a `[String:Any]` dictionary. From there, we check if any of the first `keys` are the value. If so, we return true and be done. If not, we can recursively check the children keys to see if they match; the children `keys` are the parent `values` and that is why we loop through the `dict.values` and not `dict.keys`.

```
import UIKit

let JSON = """
{
    "female": {
        "socks" : {
            "M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8" : 1
        },
        "hats": {
            "M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8" : 1,
            "M11r5zcKvZYHDKhVzKF" : 1
        },
        "shoes" : {
            "M0uaeDL7dD1eFf1tC0k" : 1,
            "M11zGpEBwKtDRp99NOD" : 1
        }
    }
}
"""

let jsonData = JSON.data(using: .utf8)!
print(jsonData)

func checkEntireDictForKey(dict:[String:Any], key:String) -> Bool {
    let keys = dict.keys
    if(keys.contains(key)) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        for value in dict.values {
            if(value is [String:Any]) {
                return checkEntireDictForKey(dict: value as! [String:Any], key: key)
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}


let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
if let dict = json as? [String: Any] {
    print(dict)
    print(checkEntireDictForKey(dict: dict, key: "M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best (performance) solution ever but it works

```
let dictSocks: Dictionary<String, Int> = ["-M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8" : 1]

let dictHats: Dictionary<String, Int> = ["-M1xR6epQQagmJ_bFqH8" : 1, "-M11r5zcKvZYHDKhVzKF" : 1]

let dictShoes: Dictionary<String, Int> = ["-M0uaeDL7dD1eFf1tC0k" : 1, "-M11zGpEBwKtDRp99NOD" : 1]


func repeatedItems(dicts: [Dictionary<String, Int>]...) -> [String] {

    var allKeys = [String]()

    dicts.forEach { (dict) in

        dict.forEach {

            allKeys += $0.keys
        }
    }

    let duplicated = Array(Set(allKeys.filter({ (key: String) in allKeys.filter({ $0 == key }).count > 1})))

    return duplicated
}

repeatedItems(dicts: [dictSocks, dictHats, dictShoes])
```

You basically create a function, where you pass all your dictionaries, store all the keys in an `[String]` and then looks for repeated keys in the array.

Comment: I did it as a generic algorithm not really with your real case, sorry about that but I think it could help you out